# Image of homomorphism is not necessarily normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can anyone think of a nice example of a homomorphism whose image is not normal? I think there must be one but am having no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Use an inclusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $\phi: \langle (1,2,3,4,5) \rangle \to A_5$ defined as $\phi(x)=x$ for all $x \in \langle (1,2,3,4,5) \rangle.$ Then the image is $\langle (1,2,3,4,5) \rangle$ which is not normal in $A_5$ as $A_5$ is a simple group.

Answer (score 10):

Consider the homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to S_3$ defined by $\phi(1)=(12)$.

Comment: im assuming here $\phi(0)=$id$_{S_3}$?